# Dynamic side input from Bigquery in python

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am coding a beam pipeline which read pubsub messages with an attribute called 'uid' which is a unique id of current message.  Then I would like to use this 'uid' to query bigquery to get additional information to enrich the message.

It may not be appropriate to use the whole table as side input since the bigquery table is very large, the ideal approach should be something like:

```py
mainInput=(p|beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.inputTopic,with_attributes=True))
sideInput=(p|beam.io.ReadFromBigquery(query= 'select * from tablex where uid="id_from_message"'))
def fn(left,right):
   for x in right:
      yield (left,x)
process = (mainInput|map(fn,right=beam.pvalue.asDict(sideInput))
```

However, I don't know how to get the 'id_from_message' because it resides in pipeline mainInput, can you please help to advice on how to do that in python?

My current code is as below

```py
class enrichByBQClient(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print("Enrich from BQ Start")
            attribute = element[1]
            query = 'select uid,status from `XXXXXX` where uid="{}" limit 1' \
               .format(attribute.get('uid'))
            client=bigquery.Client()
            query_job = client.query(query)
            result=query_job.result()

            len_result = 0
            for row in result:
                status=row.status
                len_result+=1

            if len_result == 0:
                status=OUTPUT_TAG_NEW
            elif status != 'complete':
                status = OUTPUT_TAG_INCOMPLETE
            else:
                status = OUTPUT_TAG_COMPLETE

            yield (element[0],element[1],status)

      message=(
           p|beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.inputTopic,with_attributes=True))

......
message=(p|beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.inputTopic,with_attributes=True))

enrichData,failure_enrich=(message 
|'enrich by bigquery client' >> beam.ParDo(enrichByBQClient())
)
```

I add the query bigquery logic in a Pardo Function which might not be the best practice, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's not a good practice to execute a query to `BigQuery` in a `ParDo`. It will execute to many queries and it's not performant with `Beam` and not cost effective in the `BigQuery` side.

You can think about another approach and design to solve your issue.

You have a streaming pipeline and need having a state.
If it's possible for you, it could be interesting to use a `In Memory` storage beside your `BigQuery` table.

In `Google Cloud`, there a [MemoryStore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview) cache with `Redis`.

With this approach, you can use a [Python Redis client](https://github.com/redis/redis-py) in a `ParDo` and find the element from the cache.

This solution is performant in response time and cost effective with `MemoryStore`.

However, there is a downside with this solution, you have to manage your cache and synchronize it with your `BigQuery` table.

You also have to plan a way to rebuild your cache if you loose it for any reason.

I hope this answer will help.

Comment: Since this needs to introduce a new component, I need to check with end-user. 

BTW, do you think it's good idea to replace bigquery with bigtable and access bigtable within ParDo?

Comment: I think the most performant and cost effective solution is to use a in memory storage like Redis. The use of BigTable can be expensive (depends on storage, nodes...). For the execution of BigTable query in a ParDo, it's possible, more suitable and performant than execute Queries to BigQuery.

Comment: Keep us informed please about your issue, I hope my answer will help. If the answer helped you to solve it, please upvote and mark it as solved.

Comment: Got you and thanks for the advice. I will discuss with customer about the two options: dataflow + memorystore + Bigqurey, dataflow + bigtable.